# Adding two values and send them to the server in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add two values in my form to get the sum. One value is a number and the other is a string number and here is how they are implemented :

```
<AvGroup className="col-md-6">
    <Label >Total Amount</Label>
    <AvInput disabled type="number" name="total_amount" onChange={setFormValue} 
             value={(sumOfItems + parseInt(form.delivery_amount)) || ''} />
</AvGroup>
```

`sumOfItems` is a number and I am using `parseInt` to add a string value to it and then, send the result to the server. The problem is that I always get that error as a response from the server :

Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" at path `total_amount`

Any help on how I can fix this problem?!

Comment: In all likelihood, form.delivery_amount is not convertible to a number, hence the NaN. There's no way to tell why that is from the code you included.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to just work, change

`value={(sumOfItems + parseInt(form.delivery_amount)) || ''}`

to

`value={(sumOfItems + (form.delivery_amount ? parseInt(form.delivery_amount)) : 0)}`.

This will result in 0 being added to `sumOfItems` if `parseInt` can't parse out a number.